# Numbers centered in a circle

Tags: html, css

```css
.circle{    
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
    color: #2d2d2d;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 3px;
    vertical-align: middle;}

.choice .circle{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="choice">
<div class="circle" data-attr-val="2000" data-attr-price="59">2000</div>
<div class="circle" data-attr-val="20" data-attr-price="59">20</div>
</div>
```

In the example you can see my problem, 4 or more numbers looks bad, 1-3 numbers looks good.

How can I center 4 or more numbers?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Post the html code and the css, best on jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: @damianocelent done :)

Comment: Is the circle allowed to get bigger?

Comment: @fauxserious Unfortunately, no :( I need fixed height and width

Comment: Do you want to see all of the digits?

Comment: Would you consider putting down the font size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version using `display: inline-table` and a pseudo element.

These `circle:before` rule's properties will keep the numbers centered what ever size you set for the circle (though too small will look odd), even with two lines of numbers.

```
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
```

I also used [css attr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr) to set the numbers from your "data-attr-val" instead of adding them manually.

```css
.circle {
    display: inline-table;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
    color: #2d2d2d;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.circle:before {
    content: attr(data-attr-val);
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.circle.big {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
.circle.big:before {
    content: attr(data-attr-val);
}
```

```html
<div class="choice">
  <div class="circle" data-attr-val="2000" data-attr-price="59"></div>
  <div class="circle" data-attr-val="20" data-attr-price="59"></div>
</div>

<br />2 lines, still centered<br /><br />

<div class="circle big" data-attr-val="10000 20000" data-attr-price="59"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this

**HTML**

```
<div class="choice">
<div class="circle" data-attr-val="2000" data-attr-price="59">2000</div>
<div class="circle" data-attr-val="20" data-attr-price="59">20</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circle {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:250px;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rkEMR/6505/)

Comment: I need to preserve height and width circle :(

Comment: then make a default circle which holds 4 digit no. in your code

Answer (score 1):

Remove the left and right padding, and increase the width instead by an equal amount – then you can get four digits centered in there via text-align. (More digits might still be problematic though.)

```css
.circle{    
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
    color: #2d2d2d;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0 3px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}

.choice .circle{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="choice">
<div class="circle" data-attr-val="2000" data-attr-price="59">2000</div>
<div class="circle" data-attr-val="20" data-attr-price="59">20</div>
</div>
```